# Escaping comma in java

Tags: java, sql

I have a string which is fed into the query as IN clause,which looks like this `('ACT','INACT')` which is one of the parameters to a function inside a package.when a call is made to the function from java,
it looks like this

```
call package.function(1,2,3,('ACT','INACT'),4,5).
```

When the package is called,i get error as wrong type of arguments.

It is taking the values inside brackets as different values delimited by strings

Comment: Please show us the code that has that problem. `('ACT','INACT')` is not valid Java syntax (except maybe inside a String constant), because single quotes indicate character constants (i.e. they may only contain a single letter).

Comment: What parameters are defined in 'package.function'?

Comment: Show us the code please. It looks like you're not using CallableStatements to perform the call.

Comment: Are you talking about stored procedures? It does not make sense in Java -- you will get compile time error.

Comment: @Nishant, it will make sense in Java to bind the parameters. Based on the limited data that OP is providing, I can only infer that no binding is done and that the parameters are hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `CallableStatement`, so that you don't have to worry about escaping your inputs. It would look like this:

```
CallableStatement proc = conn.prepareCall("{call package.function(?,?,?,?,?,?) }");
proc.setInt(1,1);
proc.setInt(2,2);
proc.setInt(3,3);
proc.setString(4,"('ACT','INACT')");
proc.setInt(5,4);
proc.setInt(6,5);
proc.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape `String`s to put them in SQL queries I urge you to have a look to Commons Lang and more specifically to [StringEscapeUtils](http://xlct.it/hko66m) which includes a static method just to escape Strings for SQL.